# How to skip selected table column at the time of creating cake bake template cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Can you please suggest me how to skip table column at the time of creating cake bake template

**For Example..**

I don want to create text or drop down field of "modifieduser_id" column on Add/edit template.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `masterroles` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modifieduser_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `users_id` (`modifieduser_id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the bake plugin at this time.